# Selector Patterns for Lightning Component

Tags: apex, lightning

I am trying to implement selector pattern for lightning component.
I have created this class to retrieve the data and fetch into a data table.But I am getting the following errors.

@Override specified for non-overriding method: List soco.DataImportController.getSObjectFieldList()

AuraEnabled methods do not support return type of Schema.SObjectType

```
@AuraEnabled
   public Schema.SObjectType getSObjectType(){
      return Opportunity.sObjectType;
   }

   public override List<Schema.SObjectField> getSObjectFieldList(){
      return new List<Schema.SObjectField> {
         Opportunity.AccountId,
         Opportunity.Id,
         Opportunity.Name,
         Opportunity.StageName
      };
   }
```

Does selector patterns supported for lightning? Can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it appears `SObjectType` is not supported (and so presumably neither is `SObjectField`) by the Aura serialization, the simplest thing to do is use strings instead:

```
@AuraEnabled
public String getSObjectType(){
    return String.valueOf(Opportunity.sObjectType);
}

public override List<String> getSObjectFieldList(){
   return new List<String> {
       String.valueOf(Opportunity.AccountId),
       String.valueOf(Opportunity.Id),
       String.valueOf(Opportunity.Name),
       String.valueOf(Opportunity.StageName)
   };
}
```